# Chrome devtools extremely slow using React Native Hermes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, react-native-hermes

Steps to reproduce:

1. npx expo run:ios --device
2. Choose any device or simulator
3. Run app + JS debug
4. Observe

Chrome dev tools is extremely slow. What could the issue be?

React native: 0.72.5

Expo: 49.0.10

M1 Mac

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly how it's slow? All the time? Only at startup? - We don't have that issue on Intel/AMD, so I'm curious if the cause could be related to Rosetta Translation on the M1 chip.

Comment: @Slbox it's slow all the time. To the point where it freezes.

Comment: I'm not certain that you should be seeing the "JS Debug" option. That might imply it's falling back to the old-style devtools. I forget what it _should_ say because so often it doesn't work. The old-style devtools are basically unusable with native dependencies like `react-native-reanimated` and that could be the cause.